# How to Join MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I need to add an additional join to a query but I'm not sure what to join it on.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM {$this->prefix}category c 
   LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}category_description cd 
      ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) 
   LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}category_to_store c2s 
      ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) 
WHERE c.category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "' 
   AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' 
   AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' 
   AND c.status = '1'
```

I need to now join my url_alias table via a column value like:

```
SELECT keyword FROM {$this->prefix}url_alias 
WHERE query = 'category_id=" . (int)$category_id . "'
```

-- EDITED TO CLARIFY --

This is for an OpenCart project that needs to simplify the url rewriting by adding the keyword to the existing category/product/manufacturer queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM {$this->prefix}category c 
  LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}category_description cd 
    ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) 
  LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}category_to_store c2s 
    ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) 

  LEFT JOIN {$this->prefix}url_alias u 
    ON u.query = CONCAT('category_id=', c.category_id)

WHERE c.category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "' 
  AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' 
  AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' 
  AND c.status = '1'
```

Comment: No there's no column for category_id in the table. I should have been more clear, I'll revise the question.  The column in the url_alias table is `query` the row values in that column are `category_id=12`, `product_id=345` etc.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer so the JOIN tests against a concatenated string.  Note that per the MySQL docs, [a number used in a CONCAT() call is automatically converted to a string.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! CONCAT I didn't think of that, thanks so much Peter. Works perfect.